# use-package: autoload function outside the main package file

Tags: package, use-package, autoload, require

I am trying to install [simplenote2](https://github.com/alpha22jp/simplenote2.el) to read my org files on my phone. 
The official setup method is:

```
(require 'simplenote2)
(setq simplenote2-email "email@example.com")
(setq simplenote2-password "yourpassword")
(simplenote2-setup)
```

and the app starts with

```
M-x simplenote2-list
```

In practice credentials are not necessary in clear and `(require...)` can be omitted because `simplenote2-setup` is autoloaded.

I would like to use a `use-package` declaration, therefore I am using:

```
(use-package simplenote2
  :config
  (setq simplenote2-email "email@example.com")
  (setq simplenote2-password "yourpassword")
  (setq simplenote2-notes-mode (quote org-mode))
  (simplenote2-setup))
```

(The extra line is for org-mode integration).

When I start the library with `M-x simplenote2-list`, I get an error due to a void variable `simplenote2-notes-info-version`.
This variable is defined through a `defvar` in [simplenote2.el](https://github.com/alpha22jp/simplenote2.el/blob/master/simplenote2.el). So, it seems that the `use-package` declaration is not requiring `simplenote2.el`.

The likely cause is that the autoloaded function `simplenote2-list` is defined in the separate file `simplenote2-list.el`. Therefore `simplenote2-list` requires only `simplenote2-list.el`, but not `simplenote2.el`.

If this is the cause, how can I instruct `use-package` to  require also `simplenote2.el` the first time `M-x simplenote2-list` is run?
Or alternatively: before running `M-x simplenote2-list`, how can I run the autoloaded `(simplenote2-setup)`, which automatically requires `simplenote2.el`?

Note that I have the global option `use-package-always-defer` set true.

Comment: A bug-report to simplenote2 would be good

Answer (score 1):

You cannot easily run `simplenote2-setup` when lazy loading the package.

However, there are several options, to make lazy loading happening:

---

1.
 use of `:after` and defining a use-package declaration for `simplenote2-list` i.e.:

```
(use-package simplenote2-list
  :after (simplenote2))
```

---

2.
 require `simplenote2` from simplenote2-list use-package declaration

```
(use-package simplenote2-list
  :config (require 'simplenote2))
```

---

3.
you could define a keybinding for `simplenote2-list` from `simplenote2 use-package` declaration:

```
(use-package simplenote2
  :bind ("C-c s" . simplenote2-list)
  :config
  ...)
```

This works for the same reason like the next option.

---

4.
a somewhat hacky one, declaring `simplenote2-list` as command of `simplenote2`. This works because `simplenote2-list` is required by `simplenote2`.

```
(use-package simplenote2
  :commands (simplenote2-list)
  :config
  ...)
```

---

5.
if simplenotes2 is able to be started with hooks or mode-interpreters, you could emulate the simplenote2-setup with keywords `:mode` or `:hook`. Please read the use-package manual.